# Hoeffding's inequality generalization

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Suppose I have independent random variables $X_1,\cdots ,X_n$ and a constant $L$ such that

$$P(X_i-L>u)\leq C\exp(-\frac{ u^2} { 2\sigma_i^2})$$

Does Hoeffding's inequality apply here? I only know of Hoeffding's inequality when $L=E(X_i)$, but what if we assume that $L$ is just some constant so that the above inequality holds for any $u>0$. Can we conclude that a Hoeffding like bounds applies to the sum of $X_i$? If it simplifies the question we can first assume that $C=1$.