# Does subgaussian tails imply the random variable has expectation 0?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

If you have a random variable $X$ such that

$$P(|X|>u)\leq C\exp(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

holds for all $u>0$ can you conclude that $E(X)=0$. Likewise more generally if we have two separate tail bounds

$$P(X>u)\leq C_1 \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

and

$$P(X<-u)\leq C_2 \exp(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2})$$

holds for all $u>0$ can you come to the conclusion that $E(X)=0$. I was just wondering how important the assumption that the random variable $X$ is centered is in the typical definition of subgaussianity.

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195441).

Comment: Bounded random variables are subgaussians, but they don't have zero expectation. Just take for example the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, which is obviously subgaussian, but has expectation $1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Both are false. There is a positive random variable $X$ such that $P(X>u)=e^{-u^{2}}$. This gives  a counterexample for the first part. For the second part choose  a random variable $X$ such that $P(X>u)=e^{-au^{2}}$ for $u>0$ and $P(X<-u)=e^{-bu^{2}}$ for $u<0$.